# Hibernate : FetchMode Eager vs Lazy conflict

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, criteria, eager-loading

I'm struggling with a conflict between eager loading and lazy loading.
To keep it simple here I'll use cats and owners.
I want to fetch OwnerCat entities that have a cat with a specific metadata.

My starting point is an OwnerCat.class that contains :

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_owner")
private Owner owner;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cat")
private Cat cat;
```

in my Cat.class I have a Set of CatMetadataValue.class that back references the cat class : CatMetadataValue.class defined by

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cat")
private Cat cat;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_metadata")
private CatMetadata catMetadata;

@Column(name = "value")
private String value;
```

and I need to keep it that way.

My critera building

```
    final Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(OwnerCat.class)
            .createAlias("cat.catMetadataValues", "catMetadataValue")
            .createAlias("catMetadataValue.catMetadata", "catMetadata")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("catMetadata.name", "EYES_COLOR"));
```

This gives me a OwnerCat.class with a lazy entity for the cat field.

If I swap the **Eager** fetch type from the **OwnerCat.class** 
with the **Lazy** fetch type from the **CatMetadataValue.class** 
the criteria returns me a OwnerCat.class with eager loaded entity for the cat field.

I made the conclusion that since it found two different fetchTypes for the same entityClass (**Cat.class**) : it took the last one detected.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks